# nvd3 - how to draw a line over a scatterPlusLineChart, with specific cordinates

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have plotted a scatter bubble chart using model 'scatterPlusLineChart', and its working fine. But  I need to draw a line with specific points. Please help if anyone knows.

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
  chart = nv.models.scatterPlusLineChart()
                .showDistX(true)
                .showDistY(true)
                .transitionDuration(300)
                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
  var graphData = [{key : 'Group1', 
                          values : [{x:1, y:5, shape : 'circle'}, {x:4, y:2, shape : 'circle'}]
                   },
                   {key : 'Group2', 
                          values : [{x:4, y:3, shape : 'circle'}, {x:1, y:6, shape : 'circle'}]
                   }
                   ]
  d3.select('#test1 svg')
      .datum(nv.log(graphData))
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

  return chart;
});
```

Above is the existing code and following is my requirement

Draw two lines

1) through (1,5) to (4,3)

2) through (4,2) to (1,6)

Comment: You could add the data that represents those lines.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff please specify

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, so I can't tell you that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `slope` and `intercept` groups arguments to specify the lines parameters.

For example :

```
var graphData = [{
        key: 'Group1',
        values: [{
            x: 1,
            y: 5
        }, {
            x: 4,
            y: 2
        }],
        intercept: 6,
        slope: -1
    }, {
        key : 'Group2',
        values : [{
            x: 4,
            y: 3
        }, {
            x: 1,
            y: 6
        }],
        intercept: 7,
        slope: -1
    }]
```

I let you use the [appropriate maths](http://google.com/search?q=calculate%20slope) to calculate the slope and intercept of the trend lines.